# How to use Entity.xml on Java EE 6, or what is an equivalent

Tags: java, xml, rest, jakarta-ee

So I'm imitating an example given by my professor in which he uses this:

```
 Response response = target.path("rest").path("todos")
        .path(todo.getId()).request().accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
        .put(Entity.xml(todo),Response.class);
```

And I don't have much knowledge about xml but for the project I've been told to make, in netbeans, with glassfish and Java EE 6, I don't... find anything similar to Entity. To be precise this is what I'm talking about:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/Entity.html#xml(T)

And it seems as it was created for java EE 7 and I thought well maybe there's some way to do the same operation in java EE 6?

And I haven't found a way to do it, so far, for java EE 6.

Comment: You have to look at what this line is actually doing ... it is making a PUT request to `/rest/todos/[todoID]`, telling it that an `application/xml` request is coming its way, and then sending the `todo` in XML format. I'm not aware of an easy-to-use interface like this in JavaEE 6, but the underlying concept isn't that hard; you should be able to do it using `HttpURLConnection` and the like.

Comment: I'll look into it since I didn't know such a thing existed, I didn't know that class existed, would it be too much to ask for an example of how could it be use?? I'll also look for examples of course, just wondering since right now I can't really see how could I use it in a similar fashion.

Answer (score 1):

You construct a [`java.net.URL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) object that represents the path to your RESTful resource. Then you call [`openConnection()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openConnection()) on that, which gives you a `URLConnection` which you can safely cast to an `HttpURLConnection` if your URL started with `http://` or `https://`. Use, e.g., `setRequestProperty()` to set outbound properties like MIME type etc. and use `setRequestMethod()` to make it a `PUT` request.

Next,`setDoOutput(true)` and then `getOutputStream()` to get an output stream that you can write your XML to, and do your writing. You will have to convert your object to XML yourself; maybe [`JAXB`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXB.html) and related classes will help.

Finally, you can `getInputStream()` to read the results. **Note:** once you start reading, you cannot modify your request. This may seem obvious, but I've gotten caught by this so I thought I would call it out.